# Projective limit of spaces of probability measures is bijective to the space of probability measures on a projective limit.

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Consider an arbitrary directed set $I$, and let $(K_i,\varphi_i)_{i\in I}$ be a collection of compact topological dynamical systems. I.e each $K_i$ is a compact Hausdorff space and each $\varphi_i:K_i\to K_i$ is continuous. For each $i\leq j\in I$ let $\pi_{ij}:K_j\to K_i$ be a continuous homomorphism of dynamical systems. That is $\pi_{ij}\circ\varphi_j=\varphi_i\circ\pi_{ij}$. Furthermore suppose that $\pi_{ii}=\operatorname{id}$ and $\pi_{ij}\circ\pi_{jk}=\pi_{ik}$ for all $i\leq j\leq k$. We know that the inverse (or projective I believe) limit of this system exists. Explicitly $\varprojlim_{i\in I}(K_i,\varphi_i)=(K,\varphi)$ where
$$K:=\left\{(x_i)\in\prod_{i\in I}K_i:\pi_{ij}x_j=x_i~\text{for all}~ i\leq j\right\}$$
and $\varphi=(\varphi_i)_{i\in I}:K\to K$ is defined in the natural way. It is not too difficult to show that $(K,\varphi)$ is a topological dynamical system on a compact space (equipping $K$ with the subspace topology of the product topology.)

For any compact Hausdorff space $X$ let us denote $M(X)$ to be the set of all finite valued complex Baire measures on $X$, and we know that these measures are regular. In particular we can define $M^1(X)$ to be the space of all Baire probability measures on $X$. We also know if $\phi:X\to X$ is continuous then the space of $\phi$ invariant Baire probability measures on $X$, $M^1_\phi(X)$ is nonempty.

By the Riesz Representation theorem we can identify $M(X)$ with the dual of $C(K)$, and by Banach Alaoglu we can deduce that $M_\phi^1(X)$ is weak* compact. In particular that means that we can define $M^1_\varphi(K)$ and $M^1_{\varphi_i}(K_i)$ for all $i\in I$ to be compact topological spaces, and if we consider the pushforwards $\pi_{ij*}$ for $i\leq j$ we have another inverse system $(M_{\varphi_i}^1(K_i),\pi_{ij*})$ of compact spaces, so can construct $\varprojlim_{i\in I}M_{\varphi_i}^1(K_i)$.

A nice (but I think tricky) exercise in *Operator Theoretic Aspects of Ergodic Theory* by Eisner et al. is to show that $M^1_\varphi(K)$ is affinely homeomorphic to $\varprojlim_{i\in I}M_{\varphi_i}^1(K_i)$ by the map $\Phi:M^1_\varphi(K)\to\varprojlim_{i\in I}M_{\varphi_i}^1(K_i)$ given by $\mu\mapsto(\pi_{i*}\mu)$ where $\pi_i:K\to K_i$ is the standard projection.

I am stuck trying to prove bijectivity. My idea is to use the Kolmogorov extension theorem to kill two birds with one stone, so to speak. Let $(\mu_i)_{i\in I}\in \varprojlim_{i\in I}M_{\varphi_i}^1(K_i)$. As each measure is nice and regular we know there exists a unique measure on $\prod_{i\in I}K_i$ (equipped with the product $\sigma$-algebra of the Baire $\sigma$-algebras on each $K_i$, which is actually just the Baire $\sigma$-algebra on the product space) satisfying $\mu_i=P_{i*}\mu$, where $P_i$ is the $i$-th projection on the whole product space. As $K$ is compact it is Baire measurable, so this induces a measure $\mu_K$ on $K$ equipped with the trace $\sigma$-algebra defined by $\mu_K(A)=\mu(A)/\mu(K)$.

There are two problems with this approach. Firstly I cannot see why $\mu(K)\neq 0$, and secondly for $\pi_{i*}\mu_K=\mu_i$ we would need that $\mu_i(K_i\backslash P_i(K))=0$ for all $i\in I$. This is my first time dealing with inverse limits, and I am struggling to see why this must be so. We could maybe use the fact that each $\pi_{ij*}$ is actually the adjoint of the Koopman operator $T_{\pi_{ji}}:C(K_i)\to C(K_j)$ and do some clever functional analysis argument, but I am unable to see it. In fact maybe the Kolmogorov Extension theorem is completely the wrong approach. Any pointers would be much appreciated.

*Eisner, Tanja; Farkas, Bálint; Haase, Markus; Nagel, Rainer*, [**Operator theoretic aspects of ergodic theory**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-16898-2), Graduate Texts in Mathematics 272. Cham: Springer (ISBN 978-3-319-16897-5/hbk; 978-3-319-16898-2/ebook). xviii, 628 p. (2015). [ZBL1353.37002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1353.37002). the book *Operator Theoretic Aspects of Ergodic Theory*

Answer (score 2):

Considering it has been 3 months, I will post the proof I came up with, appealing to the work of Choksi [1]. I will present the whole proof, and not just the one showing bijectivity, because I have already typed it up in TEX as such.

We first aim to prove that $\Phi:M_\varphi^1(K)\to \varprojlim_jM^1_{\varphi_j}(K_j)$ given by $\mu\mapsto (\pi_{j*}\mu)_{j\in I}$ is a bijective mapping between compact and convex sets. We work under assumption that $\pi_{ij}$ is surjective for each $i\leq j$. We proceed by first proving the following lemma:

> **Lemma 1:**
>       Let $(K_j,\pi_{ij},I)$ be an inverse system of compact and Hausdorff topological spaces. The projective limit of this system $K:=\varprojlim_jK_j$ is compact.

*Proof:*
    We first note that $\prod_{j\in I}K_j$ is compact by Tychonoff's theorem. It thus suffices to prove that $K$ is closed in $\prod_{j\in I}K_j$. To that end fix some $(x_j)_I\in \prod_{j\in I}K_j\backslash K$. There then exists some $i\leq j$ such that $\pi_{ij}x_j\neq x_i$. Fix an open neighbourhood $U\subset K_i$ of $x_i$  and an open neighbourhood $V\subset K_i$ of $\pi_{ij}x_j$ disjoint from $U$. Set $V'=\pi_{ij}^{-1}(V)\subset K_j$. $V'$ is obviously an open neighbourhood of $x_j$. Now define $W=\prod_{k\in I}W_k$ where $W_k=K_k$ for $k\neq i,j$ and $W_j=V'$ and $W_i=U$. By construction $W\cap K=\emptyset$ and $W$ is the product of open sets so is open. Thus $(x_j)_I$ is an interior point, but it is arbitrary, so we can conclude that $K$ is indeed closed and thus compact. **Q.E.D**

We know that for any compact topological system that the set of invariant probability measures on that system is compact, so we can conclude that each $M^1_{\varphi_j}(K_j)$ is compact. This in conjunction with Lemma 1 means that $M^1_\varphi(K)$ is compact. The same lemma also thus implies that $\varprojlim_j M^1_{\varphi_j}(K_j)$ is compact. We also want $K$ to be none empty, to which end we prove:

> **Lemma 2:**
>       For any $i\in I$ and $x_i\in K_i$ there exists a $x\in K$ such that $\pi_i(x)=x_i$.

*Proof:*
    Define for any $j\geq i$,
    $$L_j=\left\{(\tilde x)_{\ell\in I}\in\prod_{\ell \in I}K_\ell:\pi_i(\tilde x)=x_i,~\pi_{kj}\tilde x_j=\tilde x_k~\text{for all}~k\leq j\right\}.$$
    By mirroring the argument showing that $K$ is closed in the proof of lemma 1 it follows that each $L_j$ is closed in the product space, so indeed each $L_j$ is compact as $\prod_{j\in I}K_j$ is compact Hausdorff. Furthermore, by construction, for each $(\tilde x)\in \bigcap_{j\in I}L_j$ we have that $\pi_i \tilde x=x_i$, and for every $k\leq j$ we have $\pi_{kj}\tilde x_j=\tilde x_k$. We thus just need to show that $\bigcap_{j\in I}L_j\neq \emptyset$. We do this by utilizing the fact that in a compact space if a collection of closed sets satisfies the finite intersection property then the intersection of all the sets in the collection is nonempty. Now for any finite $\{j_1,\dots j_n\}\subset I$ we have by the definition of a directed set that there exists some $j\in I$ such that $j_k\leq j$ for all $k\in \{1,\dots,n\}$. Now $\emptyset\neq L_{j}\subset \bigcap_{k=1}^nL_{j_k}$, so we can conclude that every $\{L_j\}_{j\in L}$ is a collection of closed sets with the finite intersection property, so by the above $\bigcap_{j\in I}L_j\neq \emptyset$. This allows us to conclude that $\pi_i(\tilde x)=x_i$ for any $\tilde x\in \bigcap_{j\in I}L_j\subset K$. **Q.E.D**

The above Lemma actually gives us more than $K$ being non-empty, but actually says that each projection restricted to $K$ is surjective. We now present a simple lemma, but without proof as it is fairly simple.

> **Lemma 3:**
>       The projective limit, $X$, of an inverse system $(X_i,T_{ij},I)$ of linear spaces is a convex subset of the product $X=\prod_{j\in I}X_j$.

Lemma 3 allows us to conclude that each $\varprojlim_jM_{\varphi_j}^1(K_j)$ is indeed convex, so $\Phi$ is a map between non-empty compact, convex spaces.

We must now show that $\Phi$ is bijective, affine and continuous. To do this we appeal to the work of Choksi [1]. Lemma 2 guarantees that our inverse system $(K_i,\pi_{ij},I)$ satisfies the assumptions that Choksi works under. We can associate any $(\mu_i)\in \varprojlim_iM_{\varphi_i}^1(K_i)$ with a inverse system of Baire probability measure spaces $(K_i,\mathcal{B}(K_i),\mu_i,\pi_{ij},I)$. Theorem 2.2 and Theorem 2.3 in [1] guarantee that the inverse limit measure space, $(K,\otimes\mathcal{B}(K_i),\mu)$, of this system exists, and that this is indeed a Baire probability space. That the limit space of probability spaces is again a probability space is not explicitly stated, but this follows simply from the construction where a finitely additive set function on a generating ring of $\otimes\mathcal{B}(K_i)$ is defined in terms of the measures on each $K_i$. Furthermore this same construction gives that $\pi_{i*}\mu=\mu_i$ for all $i\in I$. So we have $\mu\in M^1(K)$ satisfying $\pi_{i*}\mu=\mu_i$, and all that is left is to show that $\mu$ is $\varphi$ invariant. This follows because on any element of the generating semi-ring of cylinder sets, of the form $\cap_{i=1}^n\pi_{j_i}^{-1}(A_{j_i})$ for $A_{j_i}\in \mathcal{B}(K_{j_i})$, we have 
\begin{align*}
\mu\left(\varphi^{-1}\bigcap_{i=1}^n\pi_{j_i}^{-1}(A_{j_i})\right)&=\mu\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^n\varphi^{-1}\pi_{j_i}^{-1}(A_{j_i})\right)\\
&=\mu\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^n\pi_{j_i}^{-1}(\varphi_{j_i}^{-1}A_{j_i})\right)\\
&=\prod_{i=1}^n\mu_{j_i}(\varphi_{j_i}^{-1}(A_{j_i}))) \\
& =\prod_{i=1}^n\mu_{j_i}(A_{j_i})\\
&= \mu\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^n\pi_{j_i}^{-1}(A_{j_i})\right),
\end{align*}
meaning that $\mu$ is $\varphi$ invariant on a generating semi-ring, so indeed $\mu\in M^1_\varphi(K)$. Thus $\Phi$ is surjective.

To prove that $\Phi$ is injective we suppose $\Phi(\mu)=(\mu_i)_{_i\in I}=\Phi(\nu)$. In particular this means $\pi_i^*\mu=\mu_i=\pi_i^*\nu$, which means that both $\pi$ and $\nu$ agree on the generating semi ring of $\mathcal{B}(K)$, namely cylinder sets of the form $\cap_{i=1}^n\pi_{j_i}^{-1}(A_{j_i})$ for $A_{j_i}\in \mathcal{B}(K_{j_i})$. However the Caratheodory Extension Theorem means that the extension of a finite measure on a generating semi-ring to the $\sigma$ algebra is unique, so we must have $\mu=\nu$.

We now show that $\Phi$ is continuous with continuous inverse. To do so we know that $\Phi$ can easily be thought of as the restriction of a bijective mapping $\Psi:M(K)\to \varprojlim_iM(K_i)$ (The bijectivity of $\Psi$ follows almost identically from the arguments given above.) We claim that $\Psi$ is linear. To see this fix some $\mu,\nu\in M(K)$. Then, for any $i\in I$ and $A\in \mathcal{B}(K_i)$, 
\begin{align*}
(\Psi(\mu+\nu))_i(A)&=\pi_{i*}(\nu+\mu)(A)=\mu(\pi_i^{-1}(A))+\nu(\pi_i^{-1}(A))\\
&=\pi_{i*}\mu(A)+\pi_{i*}\nu(A)=(\Psi(\mu))_i(A)+(\Psi(\nu))_i(A).
\end{align*}
Similarly, for any $\lambda\in \mathbb C$ we have
$$(\Psi\lambda\mu)_i(A)=\pi_*\lambda\mu(A)=\lambda\mu(\pi^{-1}_i(A))=\lambda(\Psi\mu)_i.$$
Thus $\Psi$ is bounded, and so $\Phi$ as its restriction to a map between convex spaces is affine.

We now prove that $\Psi$ is bounded. Define $J_i:C(K_i)\to C(K)$ as the Koopman operator of the projection $\pi_i:K\to K_i$, and $J_{ji}:C(K_i)\to C(K_j)$ as the Koopman operator of $\pi_{ij}$. We can define a mapping
$$F:\mathscr L(C(K);C(K))\to X,$$
by $T\mapsto(TJ_i)i$, where 
$$X=\{(T_i)_{i\in I}:\sup_{i\in I}\|T_i\|<\infty,~\text{and}~T_jJ_{ji}=T_i~\forall i\leq j\}.$$
It can be shown that $\|F(T)\|=\sup_{i\in I}\|TJ_i\|$, which is how we will show that $\Psi$ is bounded. We note that the adjoint of $(J_i)_i\in X$ is in fact $\Psi:M(K)\to \varprojlim_iM(K_i)$, but $(J_i)_i=F(\operatorname{id}),$ and because $\|J_i\|=1$ for all $i\in I$ we get that $\|F(\operatorname{id})\|=1$. Thus $\|\Psi\|=1$, and $\Psi$ is indeed a bounded operator. As the restriction of a bounded operator $\Phi$ is thus continuous. We have also proven that it is a bijective mapping between compact Hausdorff spaces, so the inverse of $\Phi$ is thus also continuous so $\Phi$ is an affine homeomorphism as claimed.

[1] *Choksi, J. R.*, [**Inverse limits of measure spaces**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1112/plms/s3-8.3.321), Proc. Lond. Math. Soc., III. Ser. 8, 321-342 (1958). [ZBL0085.04003](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0085.04003).

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but here's what I came up with while looking at that book. Note: I used different notation than the book on this one. I used $T_i$ to refer to the continuous map $T_i : X_i \to X_i$ instead of $\varphi_i : K_i \to K_i$, and I used $\phi_{i, j} : X_j \to X_i$ to refer to the transition maps.

I do use freely the claim that $(\pi_i)_{i \in I}$ separates points. This might be valuable to check for yourself.

> Let $$\left( (X_i, T_i)_{i \in I} , (\phi_{i, j})_{i, j \in I, i \leq j} \right)$$ be an inverse system of compact topological dynamical systems. This inverse system induces a dual inverse system $$\left( \left(\mathcal{M}_{T_i}^1(X_i) \right)_{i \in I} , (\phi_{i, j *})_{i, j \in I, i \leq j} \right)$$ in the category of Choquet simplexes, where $\phi_{i, j *} : \mathcal{M}_{T_j}^1(X_j) \to \mathcal{M}_{T_i}^1(X_i)$ is the continuous affine map
> \begin{align*}
> \int_{X_i} f \mathrm{d} \left( \phi_{i, j *} \mu \right) & = \int_{X_j} (f \circ \phi_{i, j}) \mathrm{d} \mu & \left( f \in C(X_i) , \mu \in \mathcal{M}_{T_j}^1(X_j) \right) .
> \end{align*}
> Let $(X, T) = \varprojlim (X_i, T_i) $. Then $\mathcal{M}_T^1(X)$ is affinely homeomorphic to $\varprojlim \mathcal{M}_{T_i}^1(X_i)$.

Let $\Phi : \mathcal{M}_T^1(X) \to \varprojlim \mathcal{M}_{T_i}^1(X_i)$ be the map $\Phi(\mu) = (\pi_{i *} \mu)_{i \in I}$. The map is clearly continuous and affine, so it remains to show that $\Phi$ is a bijection. Let $\pi_i : (X, T) \to (X_i, T_i)$ be the factor maps.

Before we prove the map $\Phi$ is bijective, we need to establish a fact about a particular subset of $C(X)$ which we'll be making liberal use of. Consider the set $A = \bigcup_{i \in I} \left\{ f \circ \pi_i : f \in C(X_i) \right\} \subseteq C(X)$. We claim that $A$ is a dense unital $*$-subalgebra of $C(X)$. Clearly $A$ is closed under scalar multiplication and complex conjugation, and contains $1$, so it remains to show that $A$ is closed under addition. Let $f_i \in C(X_i), f_j \in C(X_j)$ for $i, j \in I$. Then $f_i \circ \pi_i = (f_i \circ \phi_{i, k}) \circ \pi_k , f_j \circ \pi_j = (f_j \circ \phi_{j, k}) \circ \pi_k$, where $f_i \circ \phi_{i, k} , f_j \circ \phi_{j, k} \in C(X_k)$, so we can write
\begin{align*}
 (f_i \circ \pi_i) + (f_j \circ \pi_j) & = \left( (f_i \circ \phi_{i, k}) + (f_j \circ \phi_{j, k}) \right) \circ \pi_k & \in \pi_{k *} C(X_k)  & \subseteq A , \\
 (f_i \circ \pi_i) \cdot (f_j \circ \pi_j) & = \left( (f_i \circ \phi_{i, k}) \cdot (f_j \circ \phi_{j, k}) \right) \circ \pi_k & \in \pi_{k *} C(X_k)  & \subseteq A .
\end{align*}
Therefore, $A$ is a $*$-algebra. Finally, we claim that $A$ is dense in $C(X)$. To see this, we just need to confirm that $A$ separates points. Let $x, y \in X, x \neq y$. Then there exists $i \in I$ such that $\pi_i(x) \neq \pi_i(y)$. Let $f \in C(X_i)$ such that $f(\pi_i(x)) \neq f(\pi_i(y))$. Then $A$ separates points, so we can apply Stone-Weierstrass to confirm that $A$ is a dense $*$-subalgebra of $C(X)$, and in particular that $A$ is a dense subspace of $C(X)$.

Now we can show that the map $\Phi$ is injective. Let $\mu, \nu$ be two $T$-invariant Borel probability measures on $X$ such that $\Phi(\mu) = \Phi(\nu)$, i.e. $\pi_{i *} \mu = \pi_{i *} \nu$ for all $i \in I$. Let $f \in C(X_i)$. Then
$$\int_X (f \circ \pi_i) \mathrm{d} \mu = \int_{X_i} f \mathrm{d} (\pi_{i *} \mu) = \int_{X_i} f \mathrm{d} (\pi_{i *} \nu) = \int_X (f \circ \pi_i) \mathrm{d} \nu .$$
Since we've proven that $\int_X g \mathrm{d} \mu = \int_X g \mathrm{d} \nu$ for all $g \in A$, we can appeal to density to conclude that $\int_X g \mathrm{d} \mu = \int_X g \mathrm{d} \nu$ for all $g \in C(X)$, meaning that $\mu = \nu$, telling us that the map $\Phi$ is injective.

Now we prove that the map $\Phi$ is surjective. Let $(\mu_{i})_{i \in I} \in \prod_{i \in I} \mathcal{M}_{T_i}^1(X_i)$ be such that $\phi_{i, j *} \mu_j = \mu_i$ for all $i, j \in I, i \leq j$. Define a measure $\mu$ on $X$ by
\begin{align*}
\int_X f \circ \pi_i \mathrm{d} \mu & = \int_{X_i} f \mathrm{d} \mu_i & (\forall i \in I , \forall f \in C(X_i)) . 
\end{align*}
Before proceeding, we'll go ahead and check that this $\mu$ is well-defined on $A$. Let $i, j \in I$, and suppose we have $f_i \in C(X_i) , f_j \in C(X_j)$ such that $f_i \circ \pi_i = f_j \circ \pi_j$. Choose $k \in I$ such that $i \leq k , j \leq k$, which exists because $I$ is directed. Then $f_i \circ \phi_{i, k} = f_j \circ \phi_{j, k} \in C(K)$, and
\begin{align*}
(f_i \circ \phi_{i, k}) \circ \pi_k & = f_i \circ \pi_i , \\
(f_j \circ \phi_{j, k}) \circ \pi_k & = f_j \circ \pi_j .
\end{align*}
Therefore
\begin{align*}
\int_{X_k} (f_i \circ \phi_{i, k}) \mathrm{d} \mu_k & = \int_{X_i} f_i \mathrm{d} \left( \phi_{i, k *} \mu_k \right) \\
 & = \int_{X_i} f_i \mathrm{d} \mu_i ,
\end{align*}
and a similar computation tells us that $\int_{X_k} (f_i \circ \phi_{i, k}) \mathrm{d} \mu_k = \int_{X_k} (f_j \circ \phi_{j, k}) \mathrm{d} \mu_k = \int_{X_j} f_j \mathrm{d} \mu_j$. Therefore, our definition of $\mu$ above is unambiguous. Since this $\mu$ is a unital positive functional on $A$, we can extend it using density to all of $C(X)$. Therefore we've constructed a Borel probability measure $\mu$ on $X$ such that $\Phi(\mu) = (\mu_i)_{i \in I}$. Finally, to confirm that this $\mu$ is $T$-invariant, it suffices to observe that if $f \in C(X_i)$, then
\begin{align*}
\int_X (f \circ \pi_i) \circ T \mathrm{d} \mu & = \int_X (f \circ T_i) \circ \pi_i \mathrm{d} \mu \\
 & = \int_{X_i} (f \circ T_i) \mathrm{d} \mu_i \\
 & = \int_{X_i} f \mathrm{d} \mu_i \\
 & = \int_X (f \circ \pi_i) \mathrm{d} \mu .
\end{align*}
Therefore, we have shown that $\int_X g \circ T \mathrm{d} \mu = \int_X g \mathrm{d} \mu$ for all $g \in A$, and since $A$ is dense in $C(X)$, we can extend this equality to all of $C(X)$.